# Package natbib warning and bibliography problems

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

What are these  error below ?

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Krishna2014' on page 16 undefined on input li
ne 502.

[16 <./figure/aks smr.png>] [17] [18]
! Undefined control sequence.
l.560 \Bibliography
                   {figure/bib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. TeX macros are case sensitive, so you need `\bibliography` not `\Bibliography`. And the undefined citation means either that `Krisha2014` isn't in your `.bib` file or you haven't run `latex` - `bibtex` - `latex` `latex`.  See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: Mant tnx, In the next step , in running BibTex , I received another warning, but I am sure I entered all  the refrences in Mendeley and run the bib file, but here it is another warning:

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
The style file: elsarticle-num.bst
White space in argument---line 27 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \citation{Solomon
 :                   2016}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 29 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \citation{Lee
 :               2010}

Comment: and these warnings:                                                                                            
 Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "liou2011"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "lee"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "chang2012"                                                                        Many tnx

Comment: Bibtex reports two periods in the aux file name. Check that out. And make sure that you do not have spaces in file names and cite keys.

Comment: BibTeX cannot handle whitespace in the entry's key. `Solomon:2016` and `Lee:2010` are ok, but `Solomon : 2016` and`Lee : 2010` are not. (Note the absence or presence of whitespace around the `:` characters.)

Comment: Please edit your posting to provide the following pieces of information. (a) the bibliography style (is it really `eisarticle-num`?); (b) two or three sample entries from the bib file that are presently not found by BibTeX; (c) the corresponding `\cite` commands in the document that aren't being resolved properly by BibTeX and LaTeX. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is the error in running Bibtex( i removed the empty spaces but still the error exist)this the error: I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
White space in argument---line 55 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \citation{Liljander,Bergenwall
 :                                1999}                                                                                          
    and this is from the related line in my  tex: create positive loyalty,(Liljander\&Bergenwall,1999)/\cite{Liljander,Bergenwall1999},(Bloch et al 1994)/\cite{Bloch1994}.Moreover, in